# How to identify fully connected node clusters with igraph?

Tags: r, igraph

I'm trying to calculate the clusters of a network using igraph in R, where all nodes are connected. The plot seems to work OK, but then I'm not able to return the correct groupings from my clusters.

In this example, the plot shows 4 main clusters, but in the largest cluster, not all nodes are connected:

[image]

I would like to be able to return the following list of clusters from this `graph` object:

```
[[1]]
[1] 8 9

[[2]]
[1]  7 10

[[3]]
[1]  4  6 11

[[4]]
[1] 2 3 5

[[5]]
[1]  1  3  5 12
```

Example code:

```
library(igraph)

topology <- structure(list(N1 = c(1, 3, 5, 12, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 3, 5, 12, 4, 
6, 11, 1, 2, 3, 5, 12, 4, 6, 11, 7, 10, 8, 9, 8, 9, 7, 10, 4, 
6, 11, 1, 3, 5, 12), N2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 
11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12)), .Names = c("N1", "N2"), row.names = c(NA, 
-38L), class = "data.frame")

g2 <- graph.data.frame(topology, directed=FALSE)
g3 <- simplify(g2)
plot(g3)
```

The `cliques` function gets me part of the way there:

```
tmp <- cliques(g3)
tmp
```

but, this list also gives groupings where not all nodes connect. For example, this clique includes the nodes 1,2,3,5 but 1 only connects to 3, and 2 only connects to 3 and 5, and 5 only connects to 2 :

```
topology[tmp[[31]],]
#  N1 N2
#6  3  2
#7  5  2
#8  1  3
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What would you like returned in the case where there was no node 12 in that cluster, but all other connections in it remained the same? (I won't be able to work on this right now, but think that  clarification might help anyone who does give this a shot.)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien - THanks for your help: I believe I would want a cluster of 1,3,5 and one of 2,3,5.

Comment: So in a simple loop of 5 nodes, it follows that you'd likewise want all five connected pairs to be returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `maximal.cliques` in the `igraph` package. See below.

```
# Load package
library(igraph)

# Load data
topology <- structure(list(N1 = c(1, 3, 5, 12, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 3, 5, 12, 4, 
6, 11, 1, 2, 3, 5, 12, 4, 6, 11, 7, 10, 8, 9, 8, 9, 7, 10, 4, 
6, 11, 1, 3, 5, 12), N2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 
11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12)), .Names = c("N1", "N2"), row.names = c(NA, 
-38L), class = "data.frame")

# Get rid of loops and ensure right naming of vertices
g3 <- simplify(graph.data.frame(topology[order(topology[[1]]),],directed = FALSE))

# Plot graph
plot(g3)

# Calcuate the maximal cliques
maximal.cliques(g3)

# > maximal.cliques(g3)
# [[1]]
# [1] 9 8
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 10  7
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 2 3 5
# 
# [[4]]
# [1]  6  4 11
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 12  1  5  3
```

Comment: A workaround to the labeling is to order the data frame: `simplify(graph.data.frame(topology[order(topology[[1]]),],directed = FALSE))`

Comment: Excellent work! Can you explain why the reordering of the `topology` object gets rid of loops?

Comment: @ Marc in the box: The reordering does not get rid of loops. It is just that the function already calculate the clusters you want to have (i.e. the maximum sized cliques of all possible cliques). I am sure there are loops in the C++ implementation of this function in `igraph`.

Comment: can someone please take a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64997562/r-connecting-graphs thanks